# Server side sorting on huge data

Tags: java, sql, sorting, dojo

As of now we are providing client side sorting on Dojo datagrid. Now we need to enhance server side sorting means sorting should apply to all pages on grid. We have 4 tables joined on main table and has 2 lac records as of now and it may increase. When execute SQL it takes 5-8 mins time to fetch all records to my java code and where I need to apply some calculations over them and I am providing custom sort using Comparators. We have each comparator to represent each column.

My worry is how to get the whole data to service layer code within short time? Is there a way to increase execution speed through data source configuration?

```
return new Comparator<QueryHS>() {

                public int compare(QueryHS object1, QueryHS object2) {
                    int tatAbs = object1.getTatNb().intValue() - object1.getExternalUnresolvedMins().intValue();
                    String negative = "";
                    if (tatAbs < 0) {
                        negative = "-";
                    }
                    String tatAbsStr = negative + FormatUtil.pad0(String.valueOf(Math.abs(tatAbs / 60)), 2) + ":"
                        + FormatUtil.pad0(String.valueOf(Math.abs(tatAbs % 60)), 2);
         //           object1.setTatNb(tatAbs);
                    object1.setAbsTat(tatAbsStr.trim());

                    int tatAbs2 = object2.getTatNb().intValue() - object2.getExternalUnresolvedMins().intValue();
                    negative = "";
                    if (tatAbs2 < 0) {
                        negative = "-";
                    }
                    String tatAbsStr2 = negative + FormatUtil.pad0(String.valueOf(Math.abs(tatAbs2 / 60)), 2) + ":"
                        + FormatUtil.pad0(String.valueOf(Math.abs(tatAbs2 % 60)), 2);

           //         object2.setTatNb(tatAbs2);
                    object2.setAbsTat(tatAbsStr2.trim());
                    if(tatAbs > tatAbs2)
                        return 1;
                    if(tatAbs < tatAbs2)
                        return -1;
                    return 0;
                }
            };
```

Comment: you want to fetch and sort 2 lac records at one shot or there is any pagination involved?

Comment: If you need to load such an amount of data in anything else then batch processing, you have a design issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: @Debojit Saikia, Yes I have a pagination on both client and server side. But some set of calculations I need to perform on Java/Service layer and the apply sort.After that I have to send result list( here 0 to 20 results) to UI.

Comment: how are you fetching data from DB? using Hibernate?

Comment: @Debojit Saikia, Yes, Using HibernateTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You should not fetch all the 2 lac record from Database into your application. You should only  fetch what is needed.

As you have said you have 4 tables joined on main table, you must have Hibernate entity classes for them with the corresponding mapping among them. Use pagination technique to fetch only the number of rows that you are showing to the user. Hibernate knows the tricks to make this work efficiently on your particular database.

You can even use aggregate functions: `count(), min(), max(), sum(), and avg()` with your HQL to fetch the relevant data.